# How to sort a List which holds a values like (67.232,S) in C#

Tags: c#, list

How to sort a `List` which holds values as mentioned below

```
67.232,S
98.122,F
12.211,H
```

and so ..

Now I need to sort the above `List` value like

```
12.211,H
67.232,S
98.122,F
```

Initially I tried with below piece of code (which I got from [Sorting a List of Strings numerically (1,2,...,9,10 instead of 1,10,2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4788227/1191670))

```
 Position.Add(25.251,A);
 Position.Sort((x, y) => ExtractNumber(x).CompareTo(ExtractNumber(y)));
       static int ExtractNumber(string text)
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(text, @"^[^,]*");
            if (match == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int value;
            if (!int.TryParse(match.Value, out value))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return value;
        }
```

but its not working out for me 
Can anyone help me out please

Thanks

Comment: Does the letter means anything if u don't need it when sorting ?

Comment: whats not working out? show your code

Comment: Have added my code for reference

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the part that is numeric and use `Enumerable.OrderBy`:

```
list = list
    .Select(s => new { NumPart = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(',')), Item = s })
    .OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x.NumPart, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .Select(x => x.Item)
    .ToList();
```

Note that i've used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` because many cultures use comma as decimal separator.

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/hEyWWk)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using LINQ's OrderBy, which let's you specify a selector:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "12.211,H", ... };
var orderedList = myList
    // sort by the number column by splitting each record by comma and parsing the first field as a double
    .OrderBy(s => double.Parse(s.Split(',')[0]))
    .ToList();
```

This is slightly different than List.Sort() as it creates a sorted copy of the list rather than mutating the existing collection.

To do this via your original approach:

```
myList.Sort((x, y) => ExtractNumber(x).CompareTo(ExtractNumber(y)));

// note I've changed the use of int's to doubles since you seem to be working with fractions
static double ExtractNumber(string text)
        {
            var fields = text.Split(',');
            double value;
            if (fields.Length == 0
                || !double.TryParse(fields[0], out value))
            {
                return 0; // as in your original code, missing/unparseable values get treated as 0
            }            

            return value;
        }
```

Comment: This is dangerous since many cultures use `,` as decimal separator.

Comment: @TimSchmelter looks like the OP's formatting already relies on using comma as a field separator though.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach does not work because your numbers are not ints! If you are dealing with currencies use `decimal`. For technical and scientific oriented calculations use `double`.

```
static decimal ExtractNumber(string text)
{
    string[] parts = text.Split(',');
    decimal value;
    if (parts.Length > 0 &&
        Decimal.TryParse(parts[0], NumberStyles.Any,
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value)) {
        return value;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also choose the invariant culture explicitly if your numbers always have a point as decimal separator. The German culture, for instance, uses a comma.