# ordering a list of addresses

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have created a list which contains a number of addresses. I want to sort the list so that they will appears numerically in order i.e.

```
1 Abbey Road 
2 Abbey Road
3 Abbey Road
10 Abbey Road
```

I've tried list.sort - which does alphabetically but therefore 10 appears before 2.

My linq is limited so I was thinking there might be a way using that or using a regex.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a single field, or do you store the street number in a separate field? Also, what kind of LINQ provider are you using (Linq-To-Objects, Linq-To-SQL, Linq-To-Entities)?

Comment: It a single field just a string Containing the whole address. I'm just using/importing System.Linq

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq's `OrderBy` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) sorting:

```
list.OrderBy(street => street, comparer);
```

where `street` are the strings with the street name and `comparer` is an `IComparer` that sorts them the way you want. To sort string numerically you can take a look here: 
[Sorting a List of Strings numerically (1,2,...,9,10 instead of 1,10,2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788227/sorting-a-list-of-strings-numerically-1-2-9-10-instead-of-1-10-2)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't store the street-number in a separate field but you expect it to be in the first position, you could use this class with meaningful properties to extract all informations:

```
public class Address
{
    public string FullAddress { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Now basically you just have to use `String.Split` and `int.Parse`, for example in this LINQ query:

```
List<Address> addresses = strings.Select(s => new {
    FullAddress = s.Trim(),
    Tokens = s.Trim().Split()
})
.Where(x => x.Tokens.Length > 1 && x.Tokens[0].All(Char.IsDigit))
.Select(x => new Address {
    FullAddress = x.FullAddress,
    Street = String.Join(" ", x.Tokens.Skip(1)),
    Number = int.Parse(x.Tokens[0])
})
.OrderBy(addr => addr.Number)
.ToList();
```

If you don't want to select this class but just your strings in the correct order, you have to change the end of the query to:

```
.OrderBy(addr => addr.Number)
.Select(addr => addr.FullAddress)
.ToList();
```

Note that the `Where` filters, so "invalid" addresses are skipped. If that's not desired you could use:

```
int number;
List<Address> addresses = strings.Select(s => new { 
    FullAddress = s.Trim(), 
    Tokens = s.Trim().Split() 
})
.Select(x => new Address{
    FullAddress = x.FullAddress,
    Street = String.Join(" ", x.Tokens.Skip(1)),
    Number = int.TryParse(x.Tokens[0], out number) ? number : int.MaxValue
})
.OrderBy(addr => addr.Number)
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var sortedList = addr.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IGsVYT).

If you are looking to sort it by Sort method, then you need to implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface:-

```
public class Address : IComparable<Address>
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Add { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Address other)
        {
            return this.ID.CompareTo(other.ID);
        }
    }
```

Then you can do:-

```
addr.Sort();
```

[SortFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jCd09z).