# How do you force ordering to be numeric

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox, directory

Attempting to sort files numerically.  A list of files:

1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4. jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
20.jpg

this list would be ordered like so:

1.jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
2.jpg
20.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        string x = txtPath.Text;
        string[] path = Directory.GetFiles(x);

        string[] filePaths = path;
        foreach (string element in filePaths)
        {
            lb1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(element));
        }

        lb1.Sorted = true;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting strings containing numbers in a user friendly way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022203/sorting-strings-containing-numbers-in-a-user-friendly-way)

Answer (score 0):

They are sorting this way because they are string, and try sort lexicographically.

Try something like this:

```
string[] line = { "file1.jpg", "file2.jpg", "file10.jpg"};
Regex r = new Regex("/d+");
var result = line.OrderBy(x => r.Match(x).Value);
```

if you want a string, use this:

```
string[] result = line.OrderBy(x => r.Match(x).Value).ToArray<string>();
```

Adapt this to your needs.

the output is:

file1

file2

file10

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the number of the picture and parsed as some int number, sorted it,and after that put in place extensions.

Answer (score 0):

ls -v *.jpg

Check the ls man page.

Comment: list into a variable: Files=`ls -v *.jpg` then echo and cut.