# Sort doesnt work in Powershell for list of images

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to list the image file names from a folder using below powershell script

```
Get-ChildItem C:\TestExtraction\ps\Images | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object Name
```

I have below as output

```
image1.png  
image10.png 
image100.png
image101.png
image102.png
image103.png
image104.png
image105.png
image106.png
image107.png
image108.png
image109.png
image11.png 
image110.png
image111.png
image112.png
image113.png
image114.png
image115.png
image116.png
image117.png
image118.png
image119.png
image12.png 
image120.png
image121.png
image122.png
```

What am I missing in this simple script for not being sorted correctly like

```
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png
...
```

Comment: This is a common problem with mixed text/numbers. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022203/sorting-strings-containing-numbers-in-a-user-friendly-way

Comment: I tried this already.. still doesn't work

Comment: sort using regex.

Comment: Could you please share the code with the regex appraoch.

Comment: Per the other answer @Sean linked, use this: `Get-ChildItem C:\TestExtraction\ps\Images | Select-Object | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }`

Answer (score 1):

[Roman Kuzmin's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/6811411) in the question mentioned by JamesC works perfect.

```
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }
Gci *.jpg | Sort-Object $ToNatural |select Name
```

Sample Output

```
Name
----
pic1.jpg
pic2.jpg
pic3.jpg
pic4.jpg
pic5.jpg
pic6.jpg
pic7.jpg
pic8.jpg
pic9.jpg
pic10.jpg
```