# Natural sort in C - "array of strings, containing numbers and letters"

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, natural-sort

Looking for a proven to work algorithm for production.
[Did see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518/natural-sorting-algorithm)
but not finding much else on the web or in books.

i.e.
file_10.txt > file_2.txt

Thanks.

Comment: What natural language are you interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you already know the C standard library `qsort()` function:

```
void qsort(void *base,
           size_t nel,
           size_t width,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *);
```

That last parameter is a *function pointer*, which means you can pass any function to it. You could use `strcmp()`, in fact, but that would give you ASCIIbetical, and you specifically want a natural sort.

In that case, you could write one pretty easily:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int natural(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    if(isalpha(*a) && isalpha(*b))
      {
        // compare two letters
      }
    else
      {
        if(isalpha(*a))
          {
            // compare a letter to a digit (or other non-letter)
          }
        else if(isalpha(*b))
          {
            // compare a digit/non-letter to a letter
          }
        else
          {
            // compare two digits/non-letters
          }
      }
}
```

Some of the `else`s could be cleared up if you just `return` early, but there's a basic structure. Check `ctype.h` for functions like `isalpha()` (if a character is part of the alphabet), `isdigit()`, `isspace()`, and more.

Comment: A nice idea, but a bit oversimplified.  It's not clear why I bothered writing and testing code...

Comment: It's hard to answer the question if we don't know what he means by "natural" and he ignored the (well designed and perfectly portable) version that was linked.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a (tested) comparison function that does the job.  It understands only unsigned integers, not signed integers or floating point:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* like strcmp but compare sequences of digits numerically */
int strcmpbynum(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  for (;;) {
    if (*s2 == '\0')
      return *s1 != '\0';
    else if (*s1 == '\0')
      return 1;
    else if (!(isdigit(*s1) && isdigit(*s2))) {
      if (*s1 != *s2)
        return (int)*s1 - (int)*s2;
      else
        (++s1, ++s2);
    } else {
      char *lim1, *lim2;
      unsigned long n1 = strtoul(s1, &lim1, 10);
      unsigned long n2 = strtoul(s2, &lim2, 10);
      if (n1 > n2)
        return 1;
      else if (n1 < n2)
        return -1;
      s1 = lim1;
      s2 = lim2;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to use it with `qsort`, use this auxiliary function:

```
static int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
  const char * const *ps1 = p1;
  const char * const *ps2 = p2;
  return strcmpbynum(*ps1, *ps2);
}
```

And you can do something on the order of

```
qsort(lines, next, sizeof(lines[0]), compare);
```

Comment: I think the first "return 1" should be "return -1". Consider strcmpbynum ("", "x").

Comment: Contrary to the claim, it was not tested or perhaps the claim should be taken literally:

>  It understands **only** unsigned integers

https://godbolt.org/z/rr6-jN

`int main() {
    int rc1 = strcmpbynum("foo1", "foo1_2");
    int rc2 = strcmpbynum("foo1_2", "foo1");
    int r1 = strcmp("foo1", "foo1_2");
    int r2 = strcmp("foo1_2", "foo1");
    printf("r1 = %d, r2 = %d, rc1 = %d, rc2 = %d\n", r1, r2, rc1, rc2);
    // we only care that signs match
    if (r1 * rc1 <= 0)
        return -1;
    if (r2 * rc2 <= 0)
        return -2;
}`

Comment: The claim should most definitely be taken literally.

Answer (score 3):

The basic sort function would be standard C `qsort()`.  It is parameterized to take a comparison function, and the comparison function is what you would need to write to do the natural ordering.

Your cross-referenced question includes a C implementation of a comparison function.

A Google search 'natural sort c' shows a [SourceForge](http://sourcefrog.net/projects/natsort/) implementation.

Comment: I did see the source fourge example, I am on windows. Hoping for more of a well tested and used compare.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version for Qt, that also supports unicode:

```
int strcmpbynum(const QString& s1, const QString &s2) {
int i1 = 0; // index in string
int i2 = 0;
while (true) {
    if (s2.length() == i2) // both strings identical or s1 larger than s2
        return s1.length() == i1 ? 0 : 1;
    if (s1.length() == i1) return -1; // s1 smaller than s2

    unsigned short u1 = s1[i1].unicode();
    unsigned short u2 = s2[i2].unicode();

    if (u1 >= '0' && u1 <= '9' && u2 >= '0' && u2 <= '9') {
        // parse both numbers completely and compare them
        quint64 n1 = 0; // the parsed number
        quint64 n2 = 0;
        int l1 = 0; // length of the number
        int l2 = 0;
        do {
            ++l1;
            n1 = n1 * 10 + u1 - '0';
            if (++i1 == s1.length()) break;
            u1 = s1[i1].unicode();
        } while (u1 >= '0' && u1 <= '9');
        do {
            ++l2;
            n2 = n2 * 10 + u2 - '0';
            if (++i2 == s2.length()) break;
            u2 = s2[i2].unicode();
        } while (u2 >= '0' && u2 <= '9');
        // compare two numbers
        if (n1 < n2) return -1;
        if (n1 > n2) return 1;
        // only accept identical numbers if they also have the same length
        // (same number of leading zeros)
        if (l1 < l2) return -1;
        if (l1 > l2) return 1;
    } else {
        // compare digit with non-digit or two non-digits
        if (u1 < u2) return -1;
        if (u1 > u2) return 1;
        ++i1;
        ++i2;
    }
}
```

}