# alphanumeric sorting order of strings in C

Tags: c, string, strcmp, qsort

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Natural sort in C - “array of strings, containing numbers and letters”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343840/natural-sort-in-c-array-of-strings-containing-numbers-and-letters)

When sorting strings in C with qsort and strcmp I have the problem that alphanumeric entries, typically strings ending with numbers, are being sorted oddly like this:

- Entry1
- Entry12
- Entry2

The desired behavior is this:

- Entry1
- Entry1_new
- Entry2
- Entry12

What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use leading zeros in all your numerical portions: Entry01, Entry01_new, Entry02, Entry12, etc.  Otherwise you'll have to dump `strcmp` and roll your own string comparison function that recognizes numerical strings as integer values.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing odd about the sort; '1' comes before '2', so any string that has 'Entry1' will come before any string that has 'Entry2'.  That's just the way strcmp is defined.  If you desire a different sort order, you can always write a different sort function.

Comment: It's not the sort function that needs help, it's the comparison function.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I know that this is the normal behavior of strcmp. My question is what is the easiest way to achieve the desired behavior.