# Can I sort text by its numeric value in Python?

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have dict in Python with keys of the following form:

```
mydict = {'0'     : 10,
          '1'     : 23,
          '2.0'   : 321,
          '2.1'   : 3231,
          '3'     : 3,
          '4.0.0' : 1,
          '4.0.1' : 10,
          '5'     : 11,
          # ... etc
          '10'    : 32,
          '11.0'  : 3,
          '11.1'  : 243,
          '12.0'  : 3,
          '12.1.0': 1,
          '12.1.1': 2,
          }
```

Some of the indices have no sub-values, some have one level of sub-values and some have two.  If I only had one sub-level I could treat them all as numbers and sort numerically.  The second sub-level forces me to handle them all as strings.  However, if I sort them like strings I'll have `10` following `1` and `20` following `2`.

How can I sort the indices correctly?

**Note:**  What I really want to do is print out the dict sorted by index.  If there's a better way to do it than sorting it somehow that's fine with me.

Comment: This is called "natural sorting". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518/natural-sorting-algorithm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can sort the keys the way that you want, by splitting them on '.' and then converting each of the components into an integer, like this:

```
sorted(mydict.keys(), key=lambda a:map(int,a.split('.')))
```

which returns this:

```
['0',
 '1',
 '2.0',
 '2.1',
 '3',
 '4.0.0',
 '4.0.1',
 '5',
 '10',
 '11.0',
 '11.1',
 '12.0',
 '12.1.0',
 '12.1.1']
```

You can iterate over that list of keys, and pull the values out of your dictionary as needed.

You could also sort the result of mydict.items(), very similarly:

```
sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda a:map(int,a[0].split('.')))
```

This gives you a sorted list of (key, value) pairs, like this:

```
[('0', 10),
 ('1', 23),
 ('2.0', 321),
 ('2.1', 3231),
 ('3', 3),
 # ...
 ('12.1.1', 2)]
```

Comment: And of course you don't need to use a lambda, you can define a function the usual way and pass in the name.

Comment: Faster than the comparator version (fewer conversions/function calls).

Comment: Syntax update for python 3: `sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda a:[*map(int,a[0].split('.'))])`

Answer (score 2):

Python's sorting functions can take a custom compare function, so you just need to define a function that compares keys the way you like:

```
def version_cmp(a, b):
  '''These keys just look like version numbers to me....'''
  ai = map(int, a.split('.'))
  bi = map(int, b.split('.'))
  return cmp(ai, bi)

for k in sorted(mydict.keys(), version_cmp):
  print k, mydict[k]
```

In this case you should better to use the `key` parameter to `sorted()`, though. See [Ian Clelland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534542/can-i-sort-text-by-its-numeric-value-in-python#1534568)'s answer for an example for that.

Comment: It's better to supply the key function as Ian does. The key function gets called once for each element, the cmp function gets called everytime the sort does a compare.

Comment: @gnibbler: Yeah, I realized that after reading Ian's answer... I was thinking about deleting my answer, but I guess it might be helpful for someone that needs a more complicated compare that can't be done by passing a simple `key`.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to [Ian Clelland's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534542/can-i-sort-text-by-its-numeric-value-in-python#1534568) answer, the `map()` call can be replaced with a list comprehension... if you prefer that style. It *may* also be more efficient (though negligibly in this case I suspect).

`sorted(mydict.keys(), key=lambda a: [int(i) for i in a.split('.')])`

Answer (score 1):

For fun & usefulness (for googling ppl, mostly):

```
f = lambda i: [int(j) if re.match(r"[0-9]+", j) else j for j in re.findall(r"([0-9]+|[^0-9]+)", i)]
cmpg = lambda x, y: cmp(f(x), f(y))
```

use as `sorted(list, cmp=cmpg)`.
Additionally, regexes might be pre-compiled (rarely necessary though, actually, with re module's caching).
And, it may be (easily) modified, for example, to include negative values (add `-?` to num regex, probably) and/or to use float values.

It might be not very efficient, but even with that it's quite useful.

And, uhm, it can be used as key= for sorted() too.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a search on ["sorting a python dictionary"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sorting+a+python+dictionary) and take a look at the answers. I would give [PEP-265](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0265/) a read as well.  The [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) function is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice sorting HOWTO on the python web site: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting .
It makes a good introduction to sorting, and discusses different techniques to adapt the sorting result to your needs.