# Sorting alphanumeric keys of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a python dictionary whose keys have the following pattern

```
<some x number of digits/alphabets> <some y number of alphabets><some z number of digits>
```

I want to sort the dictionary based on this keys.
For e.g

```
01IB0610, 01IB062, 01IB064
```

should be `01IB062, 01IB064 01IB0610`

Complete example is something like this:

```
{ '01IB0610' : {'a' : [] , 'b': [] }, '01IB062' : {'a' : [] , 'b': [] } , '01IB064' : {'a' : [] , 'b': [] }
```

Final Output should be:`{ '01IB062' : {'a' : [] , 'b': [] }, '01IB064' : {'a' : [] , 'b': [] } , '01IB0610' : {'a' : [] , 'b': [] }`

Comment: The non-digit characters are always uppercase?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: a dictionary is an unordered set of key: value pairs, you cant sort it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting alphanumerical dictionary keys in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253785/sorting-alphanumerical-dictionary-keys-in-python)

Comment: 01IB062 comes before 01IB0604? is that a typo or is it before because it is shorter

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

def key_func(s):
    return [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in re.findall(r'\D+|\d+', s)]

sorted_keys = sorted(d, key=key_func)
```

Example:

```
>>> d = {'01IB0610': 'foo', '01IB062': 'bar', '01IB0604': 'baz'}
>>> sorted(d, key=key_func)
['01IB062', '01IB0604', '01IB0610']
```

Comment: you should explicitly say that a new list is returned - unlike list.sort() it does not use dict and some how give it ordering.

Comment: I did not add the fact that is dict of dict. The key is of the first dict though

Comment: @gizgok Please give a complete example with your current dictionary and the end result you are hoping to get.

Comment: @F.J I added an example

Comment: Dictionaries in Python cannot be sorted.  You can use `collections.OrderedDict` which can keep the keys in a specific order, or you can just sort the keys as in my answer and then use that result to access the dictionary values according to that order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally get the sorting criteria, but you can use an `OrderedDict` to have a `dict` that keeps particular order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re
d = {'01IB0610': 1, '01IB062': 2, '01IB064': 3}

def criteria(x):
    number = int(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', x[0]) )
    length = len(x[0])
    return length, number
d = OrderedDict( sorted( d.items(), key = criteria ) )
d.keys()
>> ['01IB062', '01IB064', '01IB0610']
```

This creates an `OrderedDict` where the order of the elements in the original `dict` is based on a hierarchical sort of the keys of those elements. The first criteria is the length of the key, ie `01IB0610` comes after `01IB064` because its longer. The second criteria is based on the digits in the key, ie `01062` is before `01064`.