# Sorting python dictionary based on keys which contains alphanumeric value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key, alphanumeric

I am new to python.
In Python, I want to sort dictionary items based on keys which is alphanumeric.

Code snippet is as follows:

```
items={'100 kg': u"apple", '500 kg': u"cabbage", '1020 kg': u"banana", '259 GB': u"carrot"}
```

I want to sort it based on their quantity in ascending order .
Is there any way to do this in Python ?

Adding ,
I sorted dictionary keys using suggested technique. After this I want to add sorted key and its corresponding value in another new dictionary so that I can get dictionary in a sorted way ,but new dictionary is not storing data as in the order that I insert.

So For that I used orderedDict of Python.

For this I am using code as:

```
import collections

items={'100 kg': u"apple", '500 kg': u"cabbage", '1020 kg': u"banana", '259 kg': u"carrot"}
sorted_keys = sorted(items, key = lambda x : int(x.split()[0]))
sorted_capacity = collections.OrderedDict()
for j in sorted_keys:
    for i in items:
        if j == i:
            print i  
            sorted_capacity[j]=items[j]
            break
```

Here I am getting error as : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict' 
What may be the reason for this?

Comment: You need a dictionary as output? That is not possible as dictionaries are unordered datatypes

Comment: Take a look at OrderedDict (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888331/sorting-alphanumeric-keys-of-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort the dictionaries as python dictionaries are unordered.

All you can get is the sorted list of keys or values as

```
>>> items={'100 kg': u"apple", '500 kg': u"cabbage", '1020 kg': u"banana", '259 GB': u"carrot"}
>>> sorted(items, key = lambda x : int(x.split()[0]))
['100 kg', '259 GB', '500 kg', '1020 kg']
```

Comment: you can't logically sort kilograms alongside gigabytes either

Comment: I sorted dictionary keys using above technique.

Answer (score 0):

I used

> sorted(items, key = lambda x : int(x.split()[0]))

for sorting keys of my dictionary , later i stored keys and the corresponding value in orderedDict since it hold order in which value is entered.