# Sorting dictionary with alphanumeric keys in natural order

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a python dictionary:

```
d = {'a1': 123, 'a2': 2, 'a10': 333, 'a11': 4456}
```

When I sort the dictionary using `OrderedDict` I get the following output:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
# Output
# OrderedDict([('a1', 123), ('a10', 333), ('a11', 4456), ('a2', 2)])
```

Is there a way to get it in the natural order:

```
OrderedDict([('a1', 123), ('a2', 2), ('a10', 333), ('a11', 4456)])
or 
{'a1': 123, 'a2': 2, 'a10': 333, 'a11': 4456}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're in luck: The [`natsort`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) module can help. First, install it using:

```
pip install natsort
```

Now, you can pass `d.keys()` to `natsort.natsorted`, and build a new `OrderedDict`.

```
import natsort
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'a1' : 123, 
     'a2' : 2, 
     'a10': 333, 
     'a11': 4456}
keys = natsort.natsorted(d.keys())    
d_new = OrderedDict((k, d[k]) for k in keys)
```

A shorter version involves sorting `d.items()` (*got this idea from [RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151445/4909087)*):

```
d_new = OrderedDict(natsort.natsorted(d.items()))
```

---

```
d_new
OrderedDict([('a1', 123), ('a2', 2), ('a10', 333), ('a11', 4456)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Short "trick" with `chr()` function on character code (no external packages):

```
import collections

d = {'a1': 123, 'a2': 2, 'a10': 333, 'a11': 4456}
result = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: chr(int(x[0][1:]))))
print(result)
```

The output:

```
OrderedDict([('a1', 123), ('a2', 2), ('a10', 333), ('a11', 4456)])
```

Comment: But this will give an error when key is 'aa11'

Comment: @Jeril, you didn't mention that the input could be arbitrary. This will work for your current input format