# How to correctly sort a string with a number inside?

Tags: python, regex, sorting, string

I have a list of strings containing numbers and I cannot find a good way to sort them.
For example I get something like this:

```
something1
something12
something17
something2
something25
something29
```

with the `sort()` method.

I know that I probably need to extract the numbers somehow and then sort the list but I have no idea how to do it in the most simple way.

Comment: what is the issue with sort()?

Comment: This has a name, Natural Sort. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-algorithm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort and probably others.

Comment: Why not just`list_name.sort(key= lambda x: float(x.strip('something')))` ?

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [human sorting](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html) (also known as [natural sorting](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html)):

```
import re

def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    '''
    alist.sort(key=natural_keys) sorts in human order
    http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html
    (See Toothy's implementation in the comments)
    '''
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text) ]

alist=[
    "something1",
    "something12",
    "something17",
    "something2",
    "something25",
    "something29"]

alist.sort(key=natural_keys)
print(alist)
```

yields

```
['something1', 'something2', 'something12', 'something17', 'something25', 'something29']
```

PS. I've changed my answer to use Toothy's implementation of natural sorting (posted in the comments [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html)) since it is significantly faster than my original answer.

---

If you wish to sort text with floats, then you'll need to change the regex from one that matches ints (i.e. `(\d+)`) to [a regex that matches floats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643073/190597):

```
import re

def atof(text):
    try:
        retval = float(text)
    except ValueError:
        retval = text
    return retval

def natural_keys(text):
    '''
    alist.sort(key=natural_keys) sorts in human order
    http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html
    (See Toothy's implementation in the comments)
    float regex comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643073/190597
    '''
    return [ atof(c) for c in re.split(r'[+-]?([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)', text) ]

alist=[
    "something1",
    "something2",
    "something1.0",
    "something1.25",
    "something1.105"]

alist.sort(key=natural_keys)
print(alist)
```

yields

```
['something1', 'something1.0', 'something1.105', 'something1.25', 'something2']
```

Comment: I could sort a list of objects which had a sub property (string) using the above as well. Just replace "text" with like "someobject", and then `return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split('(\d+)', someobject.sometextproperty) ]`.

Comment: Do you know how to extend this to the case where the numbers are floats? For example, something1.0, something 1.25, something2.0.

Comment: @painfulenglish: I've modified the post above to show how to natural sort text with floats.

Comment: To fix pylint warning W1401: Anomalous backslash in string, simply prefix the regex with an 'r' like so: re.split(r'(\d+)', text)

Comment: I've used the about code to sort my list but any ideas why I can't first remove duplicate entries ie:     attr1 = set(all_names)
    attr1.sort(key=natural_keys)

Comment: `attr1 = set(...)` makes `attr1` a `set`. Sets don't have a `sort` method, so `attr1.sort` should raise an `AttributeError`. Try instead `attr1 = list(set(all_names))`, since `list`s do have a `sort` method.

Comment: This only works with 1 number. Any easy extension of this to the case of multiple separate numbers? E.g. with the above implementation we 'unnaturally' I get results like `['sth1but10', 'sth1but2']` rather than `[['sth1but2','sth1but10']`.

Comment: The floating point sort does not work with cases such as this:
alist=[
    "something1",
    "something2",
    "something1.10",
    "something1.0",
    "something1.25",
    "something1.16",
    "something1.7",
    "something1.105"]    
Output:
['something1', 'something1.0', 'something1.10', 'something1.105', 'something1.16', 'something1.25', 'something1.7', 'something2']

Comment: You also coulde use `natsorted` function from the `https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort`