# Read files sequentially in order

Tags: python, file-io

I have a number of files in a folder with names following the convention:

```
0.1.txt, 0.15.txt, 0.2.txt, 0.25.txt, 0.3.txt, ...
```

I need to read them one by one and manipulate the data inside them. Currently I open each file with the command:

```
import os
# This is the path where all the files are stored.
folder path = '/home/user/some_folder/'
# Open one of the files,
for data_file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    ...
```

Unfortunately this reads the files in no particular order (not sure how it picks them) and I need to read them starting with the one having the minimum number as a filename, then the one with the immediate larger number and so on until the last one.

Comment: You'll need to sort the files using a natural sort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple example using `sorted()` that returns a new sorted list.

```
import os
# This is the path where all the files are stored.
folder_path = 'c:\\'
# Open one of the files,
for data_file in sorted(os.listdir(folder_path)):
    print data_file
```

You can read more here at the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

**Edit for natural sorting:**

If you are looking for natural sorting you can see this great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5967539/1982962) by @unutbu

Comment: You need to be careful with sorting strings.  Sorting ```['1','2','10']``` will return ```['1','10','2']```

Comment: @wnnmaw i accept the comment see the edit.

Comment: Pypi natsort worked for my numbered `.png` files.