# Python list is not getting sorted using the built-in sort funtion

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary named "static_mac_dict" which has a key-value items as follows:

```
'2273': {'Type': 'Static', 'Port': 'Eth1/4', 'Mac Address': '80:9B:4B:D2:C8:E1'}
```

I would to sort the dictionary based on key, and then PRINT ONLY its values.

However, I can`t do that since dictionaries cannot be sorted.

Therefore, I decided to

- Copy all the dictionary keys to a list (named keysList).
- Sort the list by using Python`s list built in sort() function.
- Iterate the sorted keys list and then print the dictionary values.

keysList look like this:

```
['1294', '1518', '2230', '2273', '2844', '3642', '3971', '816']
```

Now to the code:

```
keysList = []
keysList = static_mac_dict.keys()

keysList.sort()
print (keysList)

for key in keysList:
    if key != None:
        print dictionary values...
```

HOWEVER, I noticed that in the above code, the keyslist is NOT sorted after using the sort() function.

The sort function does work properly, only IF I convert the keys from STR to INT as you can see in the code below:

```
keysList = []
keysList = static_mac_dict.keys()

for i in range(len(keysList)):
    keysList[i] = int(keysList[i])

#sorting the list
keysList.sort()
print (keysList)

# converting the list items back to str
for i in range(len(keysList)):
    keysList[i] = str(keysList[i])

for key in keysList:
    if key != None:
        print dictionary values...
```

My question is: Why do I need to convert the list item to INT so that sort function will work properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strings sort in lexicographical order, so e.g. `"21" < "3"`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5967500/3001761

Comment: You could also avoid copying altogether by doing `for key in sorted(static_mac_dict.keys(), key=int): print static_mac_dict[key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment:

*Strings sort in lexicographical order, so e.g. "21" < "3".*

So hopefully that answer your question.

Now, if you want to convert a list of strings to a list of integers then take a look at this question: [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7368789/1798187).

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368801/1798187):

```
results = ['1294', '1518', '2230', '2273', '2844', '3642', '3971', '816']
results = map(int, results)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `sort` function *is* working properly - just not according to what you expected. It's sorting the strings in the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of their **characters**.

Python (or any other language) can't possibly know that you really want to interpret the strings as numbers - unless you tell it (see `gnibbler`'s answer).

Note that, as in most languages, sorting in python entirely depends on the `type` of the objects. Most built-in types (such as `int`, `float`, `str`, even `tuple` and `list`) have a well-defined ordering. Instances of custom classes don't have a (meaningful) order, but [you can define it if you want](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/).

Answer (score 1):

Since the keys are strings, they will be compared lexicographically instead of numerically as you desire.

you can sort them by using `int` as the `key` function

```
keysList.sort(key=int)
```

that will save you the explicit steps converting to int and back to str