# Python: Group / rearange text

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following files in a folder:

a235626_1.jpg
a235626_2.jpg
a235626_3.jpg
a235626_4.jpg
a235626_5.jpg
A331744R_1.JPG
A331744R_2.jpg
A331758L_1.JPG
A331758L_2.jpg
A331758R_1.JPG
A331758R_2.jpg
A331789L_1.JPG
A331789L_2.jpg
A331789R_1.JPG
A331789R_2.jpg
A331793L_1.JPG
A331793L_2.jpg
A331826L_1.JPG
A331826L_2.jpg
A331826R_1.JPG
A331826R_2.jpg
A335531L_1.JPG
A335531R_1.JPG
A335531R_2.jpg

How can i group them so that i get:

a235626_1.jpg|a235626_2.jpg|a235626_3.jpg|a235626_4.jpg|a235626_5.jpg
A331744R_1.JPG|A331744R_2.JPG
A331758L_1.JPG|A331758L_2.JPG

... and so on.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
files = ['a235626_1.jpg', 'a235626_2.jpg', 'a235626_3.jpg', 'a235626_4.jpg', 'a235626_5.jpg', 'A331744R_1.JPG',
         'A331744R_2.jpg', 'A331758L_1.JPG', 'A331758L_2.jpg', 'A331758R_1.JPG', 'A331758R_2.jpg', 'A331789L_1.JPG',
         'A331789L_2.jpg', 'A331789R_1.JPG', 'A331789R_2.jpg', 'A331793L_1.JPG', 'A331793L_2.jpg', 'A331826L_1.JPG',
         'A331826L_2.jpg', 'A331826R_1.JPG', 'A331826R_2.jpg', 'A335531L_1.JPG', 'A335531R_1.JPG', 'A335531R_2.jpg']

for key, items in groupby(files, lambda t: t.split('_')[0]):
    print('|'.join(items))

>>> a235626_1.jpg|a235626_2.jpg|a235626_3.jpg|a235626_4.jpg|a235626_5.jpg
>>> A331744R_1.JPG|A331744R_2.jpg
>>> A331758L_1.JPG|A331758L_2.jpg
>>> A331758R_1.JPG|A331758R_2.jpg
>>> A331789L_1.JPG|A331789L_2.jpg
>>> A331789R_1.JPG|A331789R_2.jpg
>>> A331793L_1.JPG|A331793L_2.jpg
>>> A331826L_1.JPG|A331826L_2.jpg
>>> A331826R_1.JPG|A331826R_2.jpg
>>> A335531L_1.JPG
>>> A335531R_1.JPG|A335531R_2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is quite similar to your question and it has been answered before. Can you take a look at it?
[How to sort file names in a particular order using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796598/how-to-sort-file-names-in-a-particular-order-using-python)