# python sorting filename for opencv

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to sorting the jpgs (ascending numerically) in my directory to generate a video for opencv, but I'm having a a hard time finding a solution:

```
images = []
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        images.append(f)
```

images[]:

```
['img_0.jpg', 'img_1.jpg', 'img_10.jpg', 'img_100.jpg', 'img_101.jpg', 'img_102.jpg', ... 'img_99.jpg']
```

Comment: are you trying to sort by their string or int values of their numbers?

Comment: i want them to be ascending numerically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly sort a string with a number inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside)

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
 cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file      
 success,image = vidcap.read()
 print('Read a new frame: ', success)
 count += 1
```

Comment: not sure if this is what you meant, i found an example online

Comment: sorry, i meant to ask how to sort my jpg files in my directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use Os:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
jpgfiles = [f for f in listdir('.') if isfile(join('.', f)) and f.endswith(".txt")]
jpgfiles.sort()
```

Comment: im getting:    _NameError: name 'isfile' is not defined_

Comment: updated code i forget to add two imports. and no space in `jpgfiles.sort()`

Comment: It's still outputting _'img_10.jpg'_ or _'img_100.jpg'_ before _'img_9.jpg'_

Comment: Are u expecting alpha numeric sort ? i.e. img_9, img_10  and so on ?