# i want to sort the items in python in the following manner

Tags: python, sorting

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\\Users\diodi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\September2018")
for i in os.listdir("C:\\Users\diodi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\September2018"):

    if len(i)==16:
     print(i)

for i in os.listdir("C:\\Users\diodi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\September2018"):

    if len(i) == 17:
        print(i)
```

if I use two if loops in the same for loop ill get like this 1,10,11,12...2,20,21..3,30,4,5,6

this is the output I want, is there a better way of sorting them in this order?

```
1  september.pdf
2  september.pdf
3  september.pdf
4  september.pdf
5  september.pdf
6  september.pdf
7  september.pdf
8  september.pdf
9  september.pdf
10  september.pdf
11  september.pdf
12  september.pdf
13  september.pdf
14  september.pdf
15  september.pdf
16  september.pdf
17  september.pdf
18  september.pdf
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside

Comment: Try this                                                                                                             'for i in  sorted(os.listdir("C:\\Users\diodi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\September2018")):'

Comment: @EMKAY that won't work. Lexicographic ordering of numbers doesn't match the expected output. And your current code calls `sorted` on the string, not the contents of the directory.

Comment: @EMKAY i tried but doesnt fix

Comment: @roganjosh so this is the best way of doing it ?

Comment: @timmy I have updated the comment look into it.

Comment: Either the duplicate or the link I posted. The principle is the same.

Comment: @EMKAY it _still won't work_. Please read my comment again and look at the dupes or try it out on your own list.