# How can I sort a list by numbers instead of string?

Tags: python, regex, list, sorting

I have this code:

```
import glob, os
outdir = './output/'
nstring = 'testdat_2014-12-31'
nfilelist = sorted(glob.glob((outdir+'/*{}*.nc').format(nstring)))
```

from which I get `nfilelist`:

```
['testdat_2014-12-31-21_H1.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H10.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H11.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H12.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H2.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H3.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H4.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H5.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H6.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H7.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H8.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H9.nc']
```

The H1-H12 numbers at the end reflect how I want to sort it. But right now, H10-H12 is sandwiched in the middle. How can I sort from H1-H12?

Regex isn't my strong suit and I'm unable to move forward.

I tried splitting and got this far:

```
nfilelist[0].split('_')[-1].split('.')
['H1', 'nc']
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside

Comment: @maximusdooku do you want to sort by int value or string value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want them to sort them by *int value* you could use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in the following way:

```
import re

nfiles  = ['testdat_2014-12-31-21_H1.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H10.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H11.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H12.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H2.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H3.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H4.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H5.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H6.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H7.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H8.nc',
 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H9.nc']

result = sorted(nfiles, key=lambda x: int(re.search('H(\d+)\.nc', x).group(1)))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['testdat_2014-12-31-21_H1.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H2.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H3.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H4.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H5.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H6.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H7.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H8.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H9.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H10.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H11.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H12.nc']
```

**Explanation**

The pattern `'H(\d+)\.nc'` means match any group of digits `(\d+)` preceded by an `H` and followed by `.nc`. and use `.group(1)` to get the group of digits. Then transform the groups of digits into an `int` and use them as a key for sorted.

**No regex**

If you want to avoid regex altogether use the following function as key:

```
def key(element):
    digits = (ix for ix in element.split('_')[-1] if ix.isdigit())
    return int(''.join(digits))

result = sorted(nfiles, key=key)

print(result)
```

**Note**

Finally if you want to sort by the string value simply remove the calls to the int function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sorted()` function use the `natsorted()` one from the [natsort](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) module:

```
import natsort        # pip install natsort

nfilelist = natsort.natsorted(glob.glob((outdir+'/*{}*.nc').format(nstring)))
```

(The name `natsort` means *natural sort* - as opposed to the *lexicographical* one.)

Answer (score 0):

The names that you sort have a simple and regular structure; you can survive without invoking regex. Sort the names by taking the first part of a name after the "_H", then the first part of it before the ".", and converting the result to an integer:

```
sorted(nfilelist, 
       key=lambda x: int(x.split("_H")[1].split(".")[0]))
#['testdat_2014-12-31-21_H1.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H2.nc', 
# 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H3.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H4.nc', 
# 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H5.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H6.nc', 
# 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H7.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H8.nc', 
# 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H9.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H10.nc', 
# 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H11.nc', 'testdat_2014-12-31-21_H12.nc']
```

Comment: This solution will fail if you have a file named testdat_2018-12-31-21_H0.nc ;)

Comment: @LakshayGarg According to the OP, this is not possible: `nstring = 'testdat_2014-12-31'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using a regex

```
result = sorted(nfilelist, key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
```

This key first compares these filenames with the idea that

1. Longer numbers are larger
2. If numbers are the same length then comparing numbers or strings is the same

Speed comparison with other answers here:

```
| Method            | Timing                       |
+-------------------+------------------------------+
| Using natsort     | 219 µs  ± 1.13 µs per loop   |
| Daniel's regex    | 14.2 µs ± 434  ns per loop   |
| Daniel's no-regex | 14.2 µs ± 101  ns per loop   |
| DYZ's split based | 7.50 µs ± 240  ns per loop   |
| This answer       | 2.77 µs ± 46.6 ns per loop   |
```

Timings were obtained using `%timeit` in iPython3.7 running on 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7