# Sorting OrderedDict entries according to keys in natural order

Tags: python

OrderedDict preserves the order in which entries were inserted into the dictionary. Given the OrderedDict such as:

```
{'a1': 1, 'a2':2, 'a14': 14, 'a3': 3}
```

it is possible to obtain the alphanumeric order with:

```
new_dic=OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items()))

 {'a1': 1, 'a14': 14, 'a2': 2, 'a3':3}
```

However, is it possible to sort the entries according to keys in natural order such that the outcome is:

```
{'a1': 1, 'a2': 2, 'a3': 3, ..., 'a14': 14}
```

The purpose behind it is that I want to extract only the values of the dictionary but the values should be extracted according to the natural order of the keys.

Comment: You might use natsort library https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dnatsorted

Comment: sorted has a `key` argument that you can specify according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = {'a1': 1, 'a14': 14, 'a3': 3, 'a2':2}
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k, _): (k[0], int(k[1:]))))

=> OrderedDict([('a1', 1), ('a2', 2), ('a3', 3), ('a14', 14)])
```

Comment: @cerebrou Did this post solve your question? if so, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
# you could create a new dictionary: 
import re

def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    '''
    alist.sort(key=natural_keys) sorts in human order
    http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html
    (See Toothy's implementation in the comments)
    '''
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text) ]

test = {'a1': 1, 'a14': 14, 'a3': 3, 'a2':2}
new_dict = {}
for k in sorted(test.keys(),key=natural_keys):
    new_dict[k] = test[k]
```

editing to sort even if dictionary has multiple character starts. help from [How to correctly sort a string with a number inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside)

Comment: This is no sorting the keys according to the order specified in the question.

Comment: edited to sort based on natrual order