# Sorting a Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe, sorting

Currently I have the following:

a data file called "world_bank_projects.json"

```
  projects = json.load((open('data/world_bank_projects.json'))
```

Which I made a dataframe on the column "mjtheme_namecode"

```
proj_norm = json_normalize(projects, 'mjtheme_namecode')
```

After which I removed the duplicated entries

```
proj_norm_no_dup = proj_norm.drop_duplicates()
```

[image]

However, when I tried to sort the dataframe by the 'code' column, it somehow doesn't work:

```
proj_norm_no_dup.sort_values(by = 'code')
```

[image]

My question is why doesn't the sort function sort 10 and 11 to the bottom of the dataframe? it sorted everything else correctly.

Edit1: mjtheme_namecode is a list of dictionaries containing the keys 'code' and 'name'. Example:  'mjtheme_namecode': [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'}, {'code': '4', 'name': 'Financial and private sector development'}]

After normalization, the 'code' column is a series type.

```
type(proj_norm_no_dup['code'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is the dtype of the `"code"` column?

Comment: Hi, you are looking for [natural sorting](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html). please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside) answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly sort a string with a number inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside)