# How to sort list by the numbers in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of string containing numbers like this:

```
['line_1.jpg Word930\n', 'line_10.jpg Word203\n', 'line_2.jpg Word31\n', 'line_100.jpg Word7\n',  'line_3.jpg Word60\n', 'line_4.jpg Word52\n']
```

I want to sort the numbers in the string before the space in each string from small to large,I want this result:

```
['line_1.jpg Word930\n', 'line_2.jpg Word31\n', 'line_3.jpg Word60\n',
'line_4.jpg Word52\n', 'line_10.jpg Word203\n', 'line_100.jpg Word7\n']
```

I use this code to sort list:

```
myList=['line_1.jpg Word930\n', 'line_10.jpg Word203\n', 'line_2.jpg Word31\n', 'line_100.jpg Word7\n',  'line_3.jpg Word60\n', 'line_4.jpg Word52\n']
myList.sort()
print(myList)
```

But the result is:

```
['line_1.jpg Word930\n', 'line_10.jpg Word203\n', 'line_100.jpg Word7\n', 'line_2.jpg Word31\n', 'line_3.jpg Word60\n', 'line_4.jpg Word52\n']
```

This is not right,how to fix the code?

Comment: 1) Use [sorted/sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with a key function. 2) Inside the function, extract the number from the string - possibly with a regex and int conversion. There are duplicates on both tasks.

Comment: already answered => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re` to get the value and use that in the `list.sort`'s keyfunction like,

```
>>> import re
>>> x
['line_1.jpg Word930\n', 'line_10.jpg Word203\n', 'line_2.jpg Word31\n', 'line_100.jpg Word7\n', 'line_3.jpg Word60\n', 'line_4.jpg Word52\n']
>>> x.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'line_(\d+).*', x).group(1)))
>>> x
['line_1.jpg Word930\n', 'line_2.jpg Word31\n', 'line_3.jpg Word60\n', 'line_4.jpg Word52\n', 'line_10.jpg Word203\n', 'line_100.jpg Word7\n']
>>>
```

Comment: This is very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be able to help =)

Answer (score 1):

You can sorted the list like

```
myList.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[x.find("_")+ 1:x.find(".")]))
```

That will sort the list base on the number of the file.

Answer (score 1):

We could split the string on `"."` to get the filename, split again on `"_"`, then get the number from the last item and convert to an integer. Then we can pass this to the key function of `sorted()`.

```
lst = ['line_1.jpg Word930\n', 'line_2.jpg Word31\n', 'line_3.jpg Word60\n', 'line_4.jpg Word52\n', 'line_10.jpg Word203\n', 'line_100.jpg Word7\n']

print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0].split("_")[-1])))
# ['line_1.jpg Word930\n', 'line_2.jpg Word31\n', 'line_3.jpg Word60\n', 'line_4.jpg Word52\n', 'line_10.jpg Word203\n', 'line_100.jpg Word7\n']
```