# Sorting a list with both string and integers

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am having trouble finding any questions and answers to this.

I have a list of words as below:

`['ABC11-2', 'BCD14-1', 'ABC09-1', 'ABC14-1', 'BCD11-2']`

I need to sort it like so

`['ABC09-1', 'ABC14-1', ABC11-2', 'BCD14-1', 'BCD11-2']`

But with sorted() or sort() I get

`['ABC09-1','ABC11-2', ABC14-1', 'BCD11-2', 'BCD14-1']`

I need it to sort by the unit name first, then the semester and then the unit number.

Thanks,

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside

Comment: Are the unit names always 3 characters and the semester always 1 digit at the end?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `key` argument to sorted, which will specify the order of sorting:

```
lst = ['ABC11-2', 'BCD14-1', 'ABC09-1', 'ABC14-1', 'BCD11-2']

def f(x):
    x = x.split('-')
    return x[0][:3], int(x[1]), int(x[0][3:])
    
print(sorted(lst, key=f))
# ['ABC09-1', 'ABC14-1', 'ABC11-2', 'BCD14-1', 'BCD11-2']
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. It still puts the 2 before the 1

Comment: I have also added the output of my code as the last line. Could you please check again?

Comment: It works, but I have one issue. What is the number before the hyphen matters? for example if there was an extra element ```ABC09-1``` how will this be sorted?

Comment: It has to be done differently. Sorry, but your original question didn't cover that. How would you want that to be sorted?

Comment: Your question was *"It sorts by the string but I need it to sort by the number after the hyphen"*.

Comment: It didnt, my bad just thought about it then. Its basically unit codes for college. The hyphen number represents the semester. So I would assume that it should look like this ```[''ABC09-1' , ABC14-1', 'ABC11-2']``` So the sort is first by the letters, then by the semester and then by the unit code number

Comment: Please update your question with full details, sample input and output. Hence, it won't be confusing to future readers. As of now if I answer, to your comment, it would be wrong as per the question.

Comment: Updated the question to be specific

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please find your answer (edited just now).

Comment: It works! But... for some reason with some other units the unit semester is begin sorted primarily. I assume the function ```f()``` first sorts alphabetically , then by semester and then my unit number?

Comment: Yes, it sorts as you want it to be. The `return` line in the function specifies that we want it to be ordered by alphabets, number after hyphen and then by number before hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it looks like the unit name is 3 characters at the beginning and the semester is 1 character at the end. Assuming this is the case, then you can re-arrange the characters in the course names and pass that to the `key` parameter of `sorted()`. This is simple enough that you can use a `lambda` function for the transform.

```
lst = ['ABC11-2', 'BCD14-1', 'ABC09-1', 'ABC14-1', 'BCD11-2']

print(sorted(lst, key=lambda s: s[:3] + s[-1] + s[3:-1]))
```

Outputs:

```
['ABC09-1', 'ABC14-1', 'ABC11-2', 'BCD14-1', 'BCD11-2']
```