# How can I sort scores in a leaderboard?

Tags: python, sorting

I've been trying to sort a top-5 leaderboard which includes the score and the username of the account that got the score. Here is my current code:

```
g = open("scores.txt", "r")
score1 = g.readline().strip()
score2 = g.readline().strip()
score3 = g.readline().strip()
score4 = g.readline().strip()
score5 = g.readline().strip()
print(score1,score2,score3,score4,score5)
print(sorted([score1,score2,score3,score4,score5], reverse = True))
g.close()
```

It seems to work, but it only sorts the leftmost digits of the scores, for example it sorts `100coolguy 50otherguy 10coolguy 2000coolguy 2otherguy` as `50otherguy 2otherguy 2000coolguy 10coolguy 100coolguy`.

A list of the scores, and how they should be formatted afterwards:

```
100otherexample 50example 10otherexample 2000example 2example
2000example 100otherexample 50example 10otherexample 2example
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you include the minimal code and dependencies to reproduce the problem? In this case, that would be a list of the names and scores (without the IO) and how they should be formatted afterwards.

Comment: share `"scores.txt"` and the expected result. Share the code that write to the file as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly sort a string with a number inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find `digits` then sort base digits like below:

```
st = ['100coolguy' , '50otherguy' , '10coolguy' , '2000coolguy' ,'2otherguy']

def find_int(text):
    return int(''.join(t for t in text if t.isdigit()))


st.sort(key=find_int, reverse=True)
print(st)
```

Output:

```
['2000coolguy', '100coolguy', '50otherguy', '10coolguy', '2otherguy']
```

Comment: This would given wrong results if there are other digits later in the strings; for instance `'50coolguy12'` would be sorted as if they had a score of 5012. Instead, you can use `itertools.takewhile`: `int(''.join(itertools.takewhile(str.isdigit, text)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
from natsort import natsorted
print(natsorted([score1,score2,score3,score4,score5], reverse = True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need give a custom key to `sorted` key is what is evaluated instead of the whole list item in the sorting process:

A regex implementation:

```
import re

l = ["100coolguy", "50otherguy", "10coolguy", "2000coolguy", "2otherguy"]

def my_key(item):
    item_split = re.split("[a-z]", item, 1, flags=re.I)
    return int(item_split[0])

l_sorted = [sorted(l, key=my_key, reverse=True)]
print(l_sorted)
```

Splits at any character ("[a-z]") for 1 time and ignores case with `re.I`.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions