# Sorting in a List of Dictionaries with Letters & Numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I'm trying to sort. This is what I have so far:

```py
output_list = [{'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/10'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/1'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/5'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/48'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi2/0/1'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/6'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi2/0/4'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi2/0/13'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi8/0/9'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi8/0/8'},
               {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Te1/1/1'}]

mac_list = sorted(output_list, key=lambda d: "/".join([x for x in d['port'].split("/")]))

pprint(mac_list)
```

However, it's not sorting the dictionaries the way I want.

```py
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" "C:/Scripts/Python/test1.py"
[{'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/1'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/10'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/48'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/5'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/6'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi2/0/1'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi2/0/13'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi2/0/4'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi8/0/8'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi8/0/9'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Te1/1/1'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I get it to sort it so it looks like this:

```py
[{'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/1'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/5'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/6'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/10'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi1/0/48'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi2/0/1'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi2/0/4'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi2/0/13'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi8/0/8'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Gi8/0/9'},
 {'mac': '0123.4567.89ab', 'port': 'Te1/1/1'}]
```

Comment: See [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Your calculated port key is still being compare lexicographically, not numerically. Convert it into a tuple and make the numeric portions of it integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = sorted(
    output_list,
    key=lambda d: (d["port"][:2], *map(int, d["port"][2:].split("/"))),
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi1/0/1"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi1/0/5"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi1/0/6"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi1/0/10"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi1/0/48"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi2/0/1"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi2/0/4"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi2/0/13"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi8/0/8"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Gi8/0/9"},
    {"mac": "0123.4567.89ab", "port": "Te1/1/1"},
]
```

---

Note:

`(d["port"][:2], *map(int, d["port"][2:].split("/")))` will create tuple in form `('Gi', 1, 0, 48)` etc. The `sorted()` function will then sort according these tuples.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
mac_list = sorted(output_list, key=lambda d: tuple(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in d['port'].split("/")))
```

This will convert numeric strings to `int` values in the substrings of the `port` value produced by `split()` and leave non-numeric strings as is, and sorting based on the resulting `tuple` values will get you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're looking for human/natural sorting. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5967539/16521305) covers it well.

Using the `natural_keys` function from that answer, the port string could then be passed directly to the defined function as follow:

`output_list.sort(key=lambda d: natural_keys(d["port"]))`