# Sorting list based on how big an int value is

Tags: python, list, sorting

I havent tried anything for im clueless when it'd come to this but I wish to sort a list that looks like this. the thing is a string its laid out like this though:

```
Name:intvalue:othervalue
```

I want it to sort the list by the size of what intvalue is nothing else so say theres a list like below

I havent tried any code but heres an example of what I except to happen:

```
['gop:1245:random', 'random:35:eee', 'random3:100000:efa']
```

The sorted list should end up being

```
['random:35:eee', 'gop:1245:random', 'random3:100000:efa']
```

Comment: This question might help: [How to correctly sort a string with a number inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500)

Comment: Ye I saw that and my eyes lit up but realised that it'd look at all like yk for all numbers in the string not just the middle of the string

Comment: Hi your other respond is that a loop or is it looking at all values at once?

Comment: @Notepasnoobb The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) asserts the lambda function will be called exactly one for every element in your list.

Answer (score 0):

`list.sort` method and `sorted` builtin both have `key` argument where you can pass the function that takes the single element and gets what you want to use for comparison.

So let's write the key function:

```py
def get_int_from_elem(elem):
    parts = elem.split(":")
    num = int(parts[1])
    return num
```

It can be also an inline lambda: `lambda e: int(e.split(":")[1])` but I wanted to show the full form for readability.

So let's say your list is named `my_list`

If you want to change the current list, use the method. Remember the methods that change stuff in-place return None, so you don't save result of those:

```py
my_list.sort(key=get_int_from_elem)
print(my_list)
```

Or if you want a copy (my_list) doesn't get changed, use `sorted` and save the result:

```py
new_list = sorted(my_list, key=get_int_from_elem)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
lst = ['random:35:eee', 'gop:1245:random', 'random3:100000:efa']
lst.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(":")[1]))
```

I recommend using lambda function