# Order of the file reading from a directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel

If in a directory, suppose there are 100 files with names like file.pcap1, file.pcap2, file.pcap3,....., file.pcap100. In a shell script, to read these file one-by-one, i have written a line like:

```
for $file in /root/*pcap*
do
  Something
done
```

What is the order by which files are read? Are they read in the increasing order of the numbers which are at the end of the file names? Is this the same case for all types of linux machines?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/192280/does-bashs-match-files-in-alphanumeric-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sorted by file name. Just like the default `ls` (with no flags).

Also, you need to remove the `$` in your foreach:

```
for file in /root/*pcap*
```

Comment: I have files from 890 t0 1200. If i do ls, files from 1000 to 1200 have appeared first and then files from 890 to 999 appeared. So, i guess i need to rename 890 to 0890, and so on..until 999.

Comment: what if i put in alias in my bashrc file like alias ls = ls -lrth and then run that bashrc script? Will the files be read in proper order then without me explicitly renaming them?

Comment: @JustinCarrey I'm no expert at this sort of stuff, but you could try something like this: for file in `ls | sed -e 's/\.pcap/.pcap /g' | sort -n -k2 | sed -e 's/\.pcap /.pcap/g'`

Answer (score 1):

[POSIX shell returns paths sorted using current locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_02):

> If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the
>   pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, *sorted
>   according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale*

It means pcap10 comes before pcap2. You probably want natural sorting order instead e.g., [Python analog of natsort function (sort a list using a “natural order” algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-algorithm).