# python equivalent to php natcasesort

Tags: python, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Is there a function in python equivalent to php's natcasesort()?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-algorithm

Comment: Yes, this is an exact dup, and the first question has perfectly reasonable answers—complete working implementations, links to additional information.

Comment: i'm using python 2.7, no lambda's here

Comment: @Quamis Python 2 has lambdas. http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda

Comment: sorry, I always thought its a python3 feature:D

Comment: @Quamis: Actually, `lambdas` are a feature Guido _thought about removing_ in python3, but fortunately everyone else talked him out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()

def natural_keys(text):
    '''
    alist.sort(key=natural_keys) sorts in human order
    http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html
    (See Toothy's implementation in the comments)
    '''    
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split('(\d+)', text) ]

names = ('IMG0.png', 'img12.png', 'img10.png', 'img2.png', 'img1.png', 'IMG3.png')
```

Standard sorting:

```
print(sorted(names))
# ['IMG0.png', 'IMG3.png', 'img1.png', 'img10.png', 'img12.png', 'img2.png']
```

Natural order sorting (case-insensitive):

```
print(sorted(names, key = natural_keys))
# ['IMG0.png', 'img1.png', 'img2.png', 'IMG3.png', 'img10.png', 'img12.png']
```