# python: how to sort by datetime in a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code which I was hoping would work for a list of files in a filesystem. The file names in the directory look like this:

```
directory/
    ./file-2014-7-8.info
    ./file-2014-7-9.info
    ./file-2014-7-10.info
```

The relevant code is this:

```
filetype = '.info'
dir_list = os.listdir(directory)
try:
    latest_file = sorted([i for i in dir_list if i.endswith(filetype)])[-1]
    return latest_file
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("could not find any %s files in the directory: %s" % (filetype, e)
```

This code returns the 7-9.info file instead of the 7-10.info file.

How do I get it to return the 7-10 without altering the names of the files themselves? Is there an easy way?

Comment: aren't you looking for latest_file[-1] rather than the whole array?

Comment: Look into natural sorting (natsort) for Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python analog of natsort function (sort a list using a "natural order" algorithm)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-algorithm)

Comment: If you can, then make the filenames conform to ISO dates, that is, with leading zeroes, aka `'file-2014-07-08.info'`. If not possible, refer to the "Python analog of natsort function" for answers.

Comment: I added the [-1] to the code because I am indeed looking for the string.

Comment: The sort you made is not „natural” or „human” sort. So, char by char, 7 = 7, 1<9 => 71xxx < 79. You may use natsort (available for pypy I think), or, if filename is consistent, split and strip „file-2014-7-” and sort only by numbers: list.sort(key= lambda x:int(x[12:]))

Comment: Looks like the easiest solution was to use natsort from the PyPi repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered from the ideas given in the comments section of the original question. The credit goes to cox who suggested I look in the pypi repo for natsort. Here is the code changed to work properly:

```
from natsort import natsorted
filetype = '.info'
dir_list = os.listdir(directory)
try:
    latest_file = natsorted([i for i in dir_list if i.endswith(filetype)])[0]
    return latest_file
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("could not find any %s files in the directory: %s" % (filetype, e)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fname_2_ts = lambda fname:time.strptime(os.path.basename(fname),"file-%Y-%m-%d.info")
latest_file = sorted([i for i in dir_list if i.endswith(filetype)],key = fname_2_ts)[-1]
```

the problem was that you were comparing as strings and "1" (the first part of "10" is less than both "8" and "9")

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lambda function to parse out the datetime part of the file names while sorting.

```
import datetime

filetype = '.info'
dir_list = [i for i os.listdir(directory) if i.endswith(filetype)]
try:
    sorted_files = sorted(dir_list, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[5:-5], "%Y-%m-%d"))
    return sorted_files[-1]
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("could not find any %s files in the directory: %s" % (filetype, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the list of string filenames into a data structure that can be easily sorted. For example, if the date component was treated as `int`s rather than `str`s, you'd get what you want. Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
  [
    ((2014,7,8), './file-2014-7-8.info'),
    ((2014,7,9), './file-2014-7-9.info'),
    ((2014,7,10), './file-2014-7-10.info'),
  ]
```

There are many ways to get just the date component from the file. Here's one crude way of doing it:

```
>>> def get_date(f):
...   return map(int, f.replace('./file-', '').replace('.info', '').split('-'))

>>> get_date('./file-2014-7-10.info')
[2014, 7, 10]
```

Now that you have a function to get the date tuple for each filename, you just have to apply it to the all of them:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> result = [ (get_date(f), f) for f in contents ]
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
[([2014, 7, 8], './file-2014-7-8.info'),
 ([2014, 7, 9], './file-2014-7-9.info'),
 ([2014, 7, 10], './file-2014-7-10.info')]
```

If you call `sorted` on the `result` with default options, it'll output the list in date-ascending order and you can just grab the last item.