# Python sorting files in a folder error

Tags: python, file, sorting, os.walk

I have a folder where I have names as

```
file_1.txt,file_2.txt,file_3.txt,file_10.txt,file_100.txt.
```

I am reading these files using os.walk.i want print file names in a sorted order.My code is as follows:

```
import os
import fnmatch
rootDir = "lecture1"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
   files = sorted(files)
   for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.wav'):
        print os.path.join(rootDir, file)
```

But the above code is not printing the file in a sorted order.please suggest me a way so that i can print it in a sorted order as 
follows:

```
file_1.txt,file_2.txt,file3_txt,file_10.txt,file_100.txt
```

Currently its printing

```
file_1.txt,file_1.txt,file_100.txt,file_2.txt,file_3.txt
```

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort . Basically 'sorted' is does alphanum sorting algorithim and you want natural sorting so you got to do more work for that. Either you will need to use the `re` module and write a function to do sorting or use the `natsort` natural sorting third party library as explained in that link.

Comment: related: [Python analog of natsort function (sort a list using a “natural order” algorithm)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2545532/4279)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sorted the output because

```
files = sorted(files)
```

and files is `file_1.txt`, `file_100.txt`, etc.

But as the above example, `file_1.txt` or `file_100.txt` is string, and `sorted` thinks that `file_2.txt` > `file_100.txt` because `'2'` > `'1'` (note that `''`).

To explain this more clear:

```
>>> '2' > '100'
True
>>> 2 > 100
False
>>> int('2') > int('100')
False
>>>
```

---

So you need use regex to get the number, covert it to int use `int()` function, and then set a sort key like the following code:

```
import os
import re
import fnmatch

rootDir = "lecture1"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
   files.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.search('file_(\d+)\.txt', x).group(1)))
   for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.wav'):
        print os.path.join(rootDir, file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_1.txt,file_1.txt,file_100.txt,file_2.txt,file_3.txt
```

this is lexicographic sort, you need to add custom comparator
parse filename and compare numbers in the comparator