# Creating a tuple from a string in a single line of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a tuple from a string as demonstrated below.

```
line = 'StartupGrind , 26\n' #string

w,f=line.strip().split(',') #get a tuple
w,f= (w.strip(),int(f.strip())) #make it string,int
```

Can it be accomplished in a single line?

Comment: Why do people always want "one line" in Python? You *can* do it in one line, but try to focus on simplicity and readability instead.

Comment: simply because i would like to learn how to do it if possible! and i'm still learning list comprehensions in python!

Comment: I don't see how a list comprehension could be useful here. You have two elements and you want to treat them differently. You could lose the first strip, as the later strips will do its job.

Comment: @KillBill list comprehension is not useful here. You can do something like `w, f = line.split(',')[0], int(line.split(',')[1].strip())` - I don't really like this because `split` is called twice here.

Comment: I don't know the rules but you should consider posting such questions to [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). It might be more appropriate there (packing such code into one line is a bad practice).

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to do everything in one line, your task is actually not a good example for one line code, incline to more readable and maintainable code. Though here is a one liner and it's very readable:

```
w, f = (int(e) if e.strip().isdecimal() else e.strip() for e in line.split(','))
```

Comment: i'm waiting for your comments

Comment: like @Maroun's ans as well in the comments above. looks more readable to me

Comment: This code doesn't work. '26\n'.isdigit is false. You also don't need to convert it to a tuple.

Comment: copied incorrectly from my cli, fixed, good catch @JohnHoward

Comment: Note that this solution will silently ignore invalid/unexpected input like `something, not-a-number`.

Comment: @poke i agree, but i gave my suggestion to the OP according to the string he provided

Comment: It’s not a direct critique to your answer but just a note for OP to keep in mind if they end up using it.

Comment: No, it's not very readable; it's also not generally applicable.

Comment: @EthanFurman why downvote if it answers the op's question, i actually provided information that is not general approach and he shouldn't use oneliner in his case?

Comment: unrelated: you want [`isdecimal()`, not `isdigit()` for `int()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3033342/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian agree, it would be better

Answer (score 1):

Use a one-liner only if it makes your solution better. Looks like a one-liner makes it more difficult to understand what the algorithm does.
Therefore, stay with two lines, but get rid off all unneeded `.strip()` calls and parentheses:

```
w, f = line.split(',')
w, f = w.strip(), int(f)
```

This has the fewest characters and seems to be the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not one line like you seem to desire, but works well and is readable.

```
linesplit = line.strip().split(' , ')
w, f = linesplit[0], int(linesplit[1])
```

If you aren't sure whats going on here, `strip` removes the `\n`, `split(' , ')` will create a list `['StartupGrind', '26']`, and the second line sets w to `'StartupGrind` and f to `26`.

If you really wanted this in one line I suppose this would work:

```
w, f = line.split(' , ')[0], int(line.strip().split(' , ')[1])
```

Comment: It is also much more readable. I included a version with one line.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer 2-lines variant from [@Mike Müller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35426868/4279):

```
w, f = line.split(',')
w, f = w.strip(), int(f)
```

Here's yet another one-liner, *not recommended*:

```
[(w, f)] = [(word.strip(), int(n)) for word, n in [line.split(',')]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a one line answer

```
w,f = map(lambda x: int(x) if x.strip().isdigit() else x, 'StartupGrind , 26\n'.strip().split(','))
```

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any value, simply.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this helps. But you could try this.

```
w,f = line[:line.index(',')], int(line[line.index(',')+1:].strip())
```

Comment: Are you redefining the built-in `str()` as a side effect of your solution?

Comment: sorry. i am new to Python. I didn't know that str is a reserved word. Why is there no error message when I use a reserved word?

Comment: @Ray: It isn't reserved, it's a built-in type, and anything that is not a reserved word can be rebound (aka redefined).