# Sort list of files in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list like this

```
a = ['data/1.jpg','data/10.jpg','data/2.jpg'...]
```

I want to sort this list like this manner,

```
['data/1.jpg','data/2.jpg','data/10.jpg'...]
```

I have tried lots of methods, But it is not working, How I will do?

Comment: Is the name of the jpg always an integer?

Comment: yes it is always integer @DomDaFonte

Comment: This is called natural sorting. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-algorithm

Comment: okk wait a min let me try,

Comment: working perfectly thanks, @DomDaFonte

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a function that parses the file names the way you want, and use that as your sort `key`. For the example you've given, you could do this:

```
def key(full_name):
    name, _ = full_name.split(".")
    name, order = name.split("/")
    return name, int(order)

foo = ['data/1.jpg','data/10.jpg','data/2.jpg']
bar = sorted(foo, key=key)
```