# why the sort function didn't work in this list?

Tags: python

i am new to python programming and i am in a doubt in list data type. i used sort() function and it works for all the numbers i printed but not this numbers mentioned below. why?

````
a2=input("enter marks 2 :")
a3=input("enter marks 3 :")
a4=input("enter marks 4 :")
a5=input("enter marks 5 :")

marks=[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]
print(marks)
marks.sort()
print(marks)```

>In terminal:
ter marks 1 :85
enter marks 2 :347
enter marks 3 :347
enter marks 4 :56
enter marks 5 :12
['85', '347', '347', '56', '12']
['12', '347', '347', '56', '85']
````

Comment: Note the difference between a list of strings `sorted(['10', '2', '3'])` and a list of ints `sorted([10, 2, 3])`

Comment: Your list is lexicographical ordered not number ordered

Comment: you sort strings, not numbers. i.e. in lexicographic order. Check [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449427/4046632)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sort list by first number in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772801/python-sort-list-by-first-number-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying sort strings, then it's working ok. But if you want consider like int, you will need parse to integer.
Something like:

```
marks = [int(v) for v in marks]
marks.sort()
print(marks)
```

Or you can create a custom sort, using sorted:

```
marks = sorted(marks, key=int)
```

Another way:

```
marks = sorted(marks, key=lambda a: int(a))
```

Comment: You don't need the lambda. `marks.sort(key=int)` will do.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias. I didn't remember to pass it as a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is a list of strings so the `sort()` method is trying to sort them alphabetically. Use:

```py
marks = [int(s) for s in marks]
```

then

```py
marks.sort()
```

to order as integers.

Output:

```py
enter marks 1 :85
enter marks 2 :347
enter marks 3 :347
enter marks 4 :56
enter marks 5 :12
['85', '347', '347', '56', '12']
[12, 56, 85, 347, 347]
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: there is a difference between list of strings and list of ints when we sort a `list` in python, the list of strings will be lexographically ordered and the list of numbers numerically ordered.

the problem is the `type` of the elements, to change that you can use `list comprehension`, `map` or simply iterating over the list.

in either way you have to convert the inputs into integers.

here are some ways you can achieve that.

1. first method: list comprehension

```
marks=[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]
marks = [int(mark) for mark in marks]
```

2. second method: `map` function

```
marks=[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]
marks = list(map(int,marks))
```

3. third method: iterating

```
marks=[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]
for i,x in enumerate(marks):
    marks[i] = int(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the sorting algorithm works differently on strings than on integers. `input` always returns a string, even if the inputted string is numeric. Lists of strings are sorted in lexicographic order – i.e. in ascending order by first digit, with ties broken by second digit if present, and so on.

Likely the best fix for this case is to replace each call of `input(...)` with `int(input(...))`. This ensures that all your `a` variables are integers, and so the `marks` list contains integers.

If you need `marks` to be a list of strings for some reason, you can still sort by numeric value by using `marks.sort(key=int)`.