# How do you do natural ordering for strings with negative numbers and characters?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, natural-sort

I have a list of file names that I need to open, however, the file names contain a hyphen "-" which neither os or Windows 10 naturally recognizes as a negative number. As an example, the list itself gets imported as

```
['-001.000ps.csv',
 '-100.000ps.csv',
 '0000.000ps.csv',
 '0001.000ps.csv',
 '0002.000ps.csv',
 '0003.000ps.csv',
 '0003.500ps.csv',
]
```

where -1 preceeds -100. The positions of -1 and -100 needs to be reversed and I need to preserve the leading zeros and "ps.csv" component because the files are named this way.

I attempted some solutions I found on this stackexchange, however, what most people wanted dealt with searching for positive numbers and ordering off of that. For the [natsort package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort), what happens is that -1 and -100 are put at the bottom of the list.

Converting these strings to ints or floats fails, I guess because ps.csv is inside of the element.

I copy pasted the solution from the [blogpost referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-phps-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-alg) and the same issue occurs. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, why are the negative numbers not working?

Comment: Could you clarify "neither os or Windows 10"? Maybe it's beside the point, but I'm just not sure what you mean. Maybe "neither macOS nor Windows 10"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`natsort` can be used to sort signed numbers](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/#sorting-by-real-numbers-i-e-signed-floats) like so:

```
fnames = [
    '-001.000ps.csv',
    '-100.000ps.csv',
    '0000.000ps.csv',
    '0001.000ps.csv',
    '0002.000ps.csv',
    '0003.000ps.csv',
    '0003.500ps.csv',
]

natsort.realsorted(fnames)
natsort.natsorted(fnames, alg=natsort.ns.REAL)
```

Both of these produce the same output:

```
['-100.000ps.csv',
 '-001.000ps.csv',
 '0000.000ps.csv',
 '0001.000ps.csv',
 '0002.000ps.csv',
 '0003.000ps.csv',
 '0003.500ps.csv']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list based on the first 6 characters of names:

```py
a = ['-001.000ps.csv',
     '-100.000ps.csv',
     '0000.000ps.csv',
     '0001.000ps.csv',
     '0002.000ps.csv',
     '0003.000ps.csv',
     '0003.500ps.csv',
]

a.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[:6]))
```

Result:

```
['-100.000ps.csv',
 '-001.000ps.csv',
 '0000.000ps.csv',
 '0001.000ps.csv',
 '0002.000ps.csv',
 '0003.000ps.csv',
 '0003.500ps.csv'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    "-001.000ps.csv",
    "-100.000ps.csv",
    "0000.000ps.csv",
    "0001.000ps.csv",
    "0002.000ps.csv",
    "0003.000ps.csv",
    "0003.500ps.csv",
]

import re

pat = re.compile(r"^(-?\d+\.?\d*)(.*)")

out = sorted(
    lst, key=lambda x: (float((v := pat.search(x)).group(1)), v.group(2))
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    "-100.000ps.csv",
    "-001.000ps.csv",
    "0000.000ps.csv",
    "0001.000ps.csv",
    "0002.000ps.csv",
    "0003.000ps.csv",
    "0003.500ps.csv",
]
```