# How to sort a string with digits inside?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

Hello I have a string list:

```
['American (New):182', 'American (Traditional):181', 'Asian Fusion:177', 'Brazilian:8', 'Canadian (New):345', 'Caribbean:13']
```

I need to sort it according to the digits present inside the string. How can I do this?

[Python analog of PHP's natsort function (sort a list using a "natural order" algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-phps-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-alg)

[How to correctly sort a string with a number inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside)

Looked at these and tried applying it to my program but didn't work. Maybe its the ':' thats making them not work properly?

Comment: You can create a function that, using a regex, returns the number from the string, then use it as a sorting key.

Comment: Your don't even really need a regex to do what @Swifty suggests

Answer (score 0):

use key option of sort parse the number and use as key for sorting

```
lst=['American (New):182', 'American (Traditional):181', 'Asian Fusion:177', 'Brazilian:8', 'Canadian (New):345', 'Caribbean:13']
lst.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split(":")[-1]))
print(lst)
```

```
['Brazilian:8', 'Caribbean:13', 'Asian Fusion:177', 'American (Traditional):181', 'American (New):182', 'Canadian (New):345']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try and use a dictionary for this, but this should do the trick:

```py
listname.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[-1]))
```

Comment: I suggest either using `x.rsplit(':')[1]`, or `x.split(':')[-1]`, but not `x.split(':')[1]`, in order to make it more robust to a string that contains extra `':'` in the first part. For instance if `'Asian: Fusion:177'` is a string in the list, you want to isolate the right-most split element, not the element at position 1.

Comment: Absolutely true, I will include that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that extracts the number from each string, then use it as a sorting key:

```
import re
def string_to_number(my_string):
    return int(re.findall(':(\d+)', my_string)[0])

a=['American (New):182', 'American (Traditional):181', 'Asian Fusion:177', 'Brazilian:8', 'Canadian (New):345', 'Caribbean:13']

sorted_a = sorted(a, key = string_to_number)
```

Comment: It would be more robust to search for digits preceded by a colon

Comment: Indeed; I based by implementation on there being only one number in the string (but then I could have simply split around the ':' ;) ); I'll update my answer, thanks.