# Sorting a list of variable length integers delimited by decimal points

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm in need of some help.

I have a list of delimited integer values that I need to sort.  An example:

Typical (alpha?) sort:

1.1.32.22

11.2.4

2.1.3.4

2.11.23.1.2

2.3.7

3.12.3.5

Correct (numerical) sort:

1.1.32.22

2.1.3.4

2.3.7

2.11.23.1.2

3.12.3.5

11.2.4

I'm having trouble figuring out how to setup the algorithm to do such a sort with *n* number of decimal delimiters and *m* number of integer fields.

Any ideas?  This has to have been done before.  Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks a bunch!
-Daniel

Comment: This looks like my old library's sorting system. : P

Answer (score 3):

All you really need to do is to write "compare()" and then you can plug that into any sort algorithm.

To write compare, compare each field from left to right, and if any field is higher, return that that argument is higher.  If one argument is shorter, assume that remaining fields are 0.

Comment: My environment is C#.  If possible could you provide a code sample?

Comment: Sorry, I don't write C#... it wasn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

[`versionsort`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/versionsort) does exactly what you're looking for.

The comparison algorithm is [`strverscmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strverscmp), here's a description of it from the man page:

> What this function does is the
>   following. If both strings are equal,
>   return 0. Otherwise find the position
>   between two bytes with the property
>   that before it both strings are equal,
>   while directly after it there is a
>   difference. Find the largest
>   consecutive digit strings containing
>   (or starting at, or ending at) this
>   position. If one or both of these is
>   empty, then return what strcmp() would
>   have returned (numerical ordering of
>   byte values). Otherwise, compare both
>   digit strings numerically, where digit
>   strings with one or more leading
>   zeroes are interpreted as if they have
>   a decimal point in front (so that in
>   particular digit strings with more
>   leading zeroes come before digit
>   strings with fewer leading zeroes).
>   Thus, the ordering is 000, 00, 01,
>   010, 09, 0, 1, 9, 10.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Answer (score 0):

It is called *natural* sort. See [Natural Sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518/natural-sorting-algorithm).
For example, [Darius Bacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518/natural-sorting-algorithm/341730#341730) in Python:

```
def sorted_nicely(strings): 
    "Sort strings the way humans are said to expect."
    return sorted(strings, key=natural_sort_key)

def natural_sort_key(key):
    import re
    return [int(t) if t.isdigit() else t for t in re.split(r'(\d+)', key)]
```

Answer (score -1):

General solution is to convert this string into array of bytes, then use qsort and specify comparison function.