# javascript natural sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, natural-sort

I have this array :

```
var columnArray =
['columnNumber1','columnNumber6','coulmnNumber7','columnNumber11','columnNumber12'];
```

If I do `columnArray.sort();`, it gives me :

```
columnArray:
['columnNumber1','columnNumber11','coulmnNumber12','columnNumber6','columnNumber7']
```

How can I sort it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort JavaScript String Array containing numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108530/sort-javascript-string-array-containing-numbers)

Comment: see `natural sort of text and numbers, JavaScript` on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/natural-sort-of-text-and-numbers-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use `localeCompare()`, the options of which are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Now we can sort this array

```
const items = ['3rd', 'Apple', '24th', '99 in the shade', 'Dec3', 'Dec', 'Dec20', '10000', 'house', 'house11b', 'house11a', 'house99', '101', '$1.23'];
```

with one line of code

```
items.sort( ( a, b ) => a.localeCompare( b, navigator.languages[ 0 ] || navigator.language, { numeric: true, ignorePunctuation: true } ) );
```

yielding

```
['$1.23', '3rd', '24th', '99 in the shade', '101', '10000', 'Apple', 'Dec', 'Dec3', 'Dec20', 'house', 'house11a', 'house11b', 'house99']
```

Credit for this elegant solution belongs [here](https://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2019/07/19/The-better-way-to-do-natural-sort-in-JavaScript/).

#### EDIT

I'm not satisfied. This works, but only for *strings*. I'd like to have a sort that will chew on *numbers* and *arrays* too. I really want a one-size-fits-all, if I can get it. With that in mind, this update

```
items.sort( ( a, b ) => ( a + '' ).localeCompare( b, navigator.languages[ 0 ] || navigator.language, { numeric: true, ignorePunctuation: true } ) );
```

using this updated array (containing strings, integers, decimals and a nested array **['a',1,2]**)

```
let items = ['3rd', 'Apple', .99, '24th', 'apple.sauce', '99 in the shade', 99, 'Dec3', 'B', 'a', 'Dec', 'Dec20', 12, '10000', 'house', 1.24, '1.22', 'house11b', 1, 'house11a', 'house99', '101', 400.23, '$1.23', ['a',1,2]];
```

gets us closer with

```
['$1.23', 0.99, 1, '1.22', 1.24, '3rd', 12, '24th', 99, '99 in the shade', '101', 400.23, '10000', 'a', Array(3), 'Apple', 'apple.sauce', 'B', 'Dec', 'Dec3', 'Dec20', 'house', 'house11a', 'house11b', 'house99']
```

#### LASTLY

Now, to satisfy my own OCD tendencies, I want the currency value **$1.23** to line up with the rest of the decimal values. Since indulging OCD often comes at a cost, I'm using this ugly ternary:

```
( a + '' ).substr( 0, 1 ) === '$' ? ( a + '' ).substr( 1, ( a + '' ).length ) : ( a + '' )
```

Also, I'll specify the language instead of grabbing it from the browser and set base sensitivity (which is language dependent).

So a case insensitive sort `ignorePunctuation: true` that treats strings as numbers (as much as possible) `numeric: true`, and respects the order of graphemes in the language `sensitivity: 'base'` as well as sorts USD currency as decimals, is this

```
items.sort( ( a, b ) => ( ( a + '' ).substr( 0, 1 ) === '$' ? ( a + '' ).substr( 1, ( a + '' ).length ) : ( a + '' ) ).localeCompare( b, 'en', { ignorePunctuation: true, numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' } ) );
```

which gives us this

```
[0.99, 1, '1.22', '$1.23', 1.24, '3rd', 12, '24th', 99, '99 in the shade', '101', 400.23, '10000', 'a', Array(3), 'Apple', 'apple.sauce', 'B', 'Dec', 'Dec3', 'Dec20', 'house', 'house11a', 'house11b', 'house99']
```

which is as close to a perfect one-size-fits-all as I need it to be.

Answer (score 17):

Try like this:

```
arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return +/\d+/.exec(a)[0] - +/\d+/.exec(b)[0];
});
```

**Edit:** Fixed it works now, it had a couple errors: http://jsbin.com/iwejik/1/edit

Comment: Yup, you were right, I was too fast to post, forgot to cast number and grab multiple numbers, that was the issue mainly.

Comment: Instead of `>` it should be `-`. Please check the description of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

Comment: I believe it crashes when you don't have any numbers in a or b

Comment: works like a charm even if numbers and letters are in different positions

Comment: Your example on jsbin doesn't work for me at all. I got warnings about the backslash before the "d"s. However, I copied the code to JSFiddle and it worked fine. Also, while your answer technically answers the asker's question, it doesn't work at all if the array items don't contain digits.

Comment: TypeError: /\d+/.exec(...) is null

Answer (score 2):

```
columnArray.sort(function(a,b) {
     return parseInt(a.match(/\d+/)[0],10) - parseInt(b.match(/\d+/)[0],10);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rkZbu/)

Comment: As Lance observed with the accepted answer, "while your answer technically answers the asker's question, it doesn't work at all if the array items don't contain digits."

Answer (score 2):

The selected solution is not quite accurate, you can catch error if your array contains elements without numbers:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '/\d+/.exec(b)[0]')

This function will also properly sort strings like "1A" and "1B":

```js
var arr = ["house11b", "house2", "house", "house10", "house1", "house11a"];
const natural = (a, b) => {
    var an = (/\d+/.exec(a) || [''])[0];
    var bn = (/\d+/.exec(b) || [''])[0];
    return an == bn ? (a > b ? 1 : -1) : an - bn;
}

console.log(
    arr.sort((a, b) => natural(a, b))
);
```

Comment: Much better, but fails to accurately sort when the string contains no number, e.g. this fails: `["house11b", "house2", "house10", "house1", "house", "house11a"];`

Comment: Thank you, I've improved the function.