# javascript - Sorting array by use only number in strings

Tags: javascript

I would like to sort

`array = ['3 a','4 v','2 x','1 j','2 x']`

The result should be

```
array = ['1 j','2 x','2 x','3 a','4 v']
```

It should be use only number to sorting.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3108797/295783

Comment: Should it sort 1 c, 2 e, 100 q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
var data = ['3 a','4 v','2 x','1 j','2 x'];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
});

console.log(data);
```

If data looks like this `['a 3','v 5','2 x','1 j','2 x'];` you can use this approach

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
  a = (a = a.match(/\d+/)) && a[0];
  b = (b = b.match(/\d+/)) && b[0];

  return a - b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have other formatting than "number blankspace letter" you could use this:

```
var data = ['3 a','4 v','2 x','1 j','2 x', '100 y'],
    regex = /[0-9]+/g

data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (a.match(regex)[0] || 0) - (b.match(regex)[0] || 0)
});

console.log(data);
```

Works for "jdhsbfyus00789iutasvd iush d" also.

It takes the first number, e. g. if it was a string like this: "hfjf02 uy fdi88" it would have 2 as value.

You could modify the regex certainly if you would search for something else.

Hope it helps :)