# Javascript sort string with numbers at the end of dupliacte strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, duplicates

I am trying to sort an array by "itemCommodity". I need to sort my array by the smallest number at the start of the string and the highest number at the end. For example:

`["Untitled Form - 16", "Untitled Form - 1", "Untitled Form - 7", "Untitled Form - 2", "Untitled Form - 3", "Untitled Form - 4", "Untitled Form - 5", "Untitled Form - 8", "Untitled Form"];`

Should be displayed as:

`["Untitled Form", "Untitled Form - 1", "Untitled Form - 2", "Untitled Form - 3", "Untitled Form - 4", "Untitled Form - 5", "Untitled Form - 7", "Untitled Form - 8", "Untitled Form - 16"];`

I hope someone can help me out with this.

Comment: Or [Sort JavaScript String Array containing numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3108530/215552), which is a duplicate of that.