# How do I check if raw input is integer in python 2.7?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, integer, raw-input

Is there a method that I can use to check if a `raw_input` is an integer?

I found this method after researching in the web:

```
print isinstance(raw_input("number: ")), int)
```

but when I run it and input `4` for example, I get `FALSE`.
I'm kind of new to python, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`isinstance(raw_input("number: ")), int)` always yields `False` because `raw_input` return string object as a result.

Use `try: int(...) ... except ValueError`:

```
number = raw_input("number: ")
try:
    int(number)
except ValueError:
    print False
else:
    print True
```

or use [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.isdigit):

```
print raw_input("number: ").isdigit()
```

**NOTE** The second one yields `False` for `-4` because it contains non-digits character. Use the second one if you want digits only.

**UPDATE** As J.F. Sebastian pointed out, `str.isdigit` is locale-dependent (Windows). It might return `True` even `int()` would raise ValueError for the input.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'cp1252'
>>> '\xb2'.isdigit()  # SUPERSCRIPT TWO
False
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Danish')
'Danish_Denmark.1252'
>>> '\xb2'.isdigit()
True
>>> int('\xb2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xb2'
```

Comment: Or, if they want to turn the variable into a number, `number = int(number)`

Comment: `str.isdigit()` may depend on locale (because Microsoft) i.e., it might return `True` even `int()` would raise ValueError for the input.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, `raw_input()` returns a `str` object, not an `unicode` object. So I think `str.isdigit` will work as expected. Could you give me an example.

Comment: [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.isdigit#str.isdigit): *"For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent."*.

Comment: `'\xb2'.isdigit()` might be true on Python 2 if locale uses cp1252 character encoding (on Windows).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Thank you for the information. I am trying to reproduce it myself. I'll update the answer as soon as I reproduce it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I updated answer according to you. BTW, I couldn't reproduce it. http://i.imgur.com/pHvgZOY.png . Could you give me any hint? I'm ready to change language/locale and reboot ;)

Comment: use cp1252 locale, not cp1251. PYTHONIOENCODING is unrelated.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I could reproduce it thanks to you. Nice to know it. Going back to my original langauge :)

Comment: have you checked that `int('\xb2')` raises `ValueError` in Danish locale?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Yes, I checked it: http://i.imgur.com/BglM8Ol.png . I forgot to paste that part. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 8):

You can do it this way:

```
try:
    val = int(raw_input("number: "))
except ValueError:
    # not an integer
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method .isdigit(), see example below.

```
user_input = raw_input()
if user_input.isdigit():
    print "That is a number."

else:
    print "That is not a number."
```

If you require the input to remain digit for further use, you can add something like:

```
new_variable = int(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
`x =raw_input('Enter a number or a word: ')
y = x.isdigit()
if (y == False):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        print('I'),
else:
    for i in range(int(x)):
        print('I'),
```

`

Comment: Please consider editing your post to explain how this works as code only answers don't always make it clear to the OP how to resolve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
def checker():
  inputt = raw_input("how many u want to check?")
  try:
      return int(inputt)
  except ValueError:
      print "Error!, pls enter int!"
      return checker()
```