# How to validate python raw_input for digits

Tags: python

```
# Validating for only numbers in python one after another(in sequence)

a = raw_input()

#if a is a number then it should take next raw_input i.e., 'b' else it should ask for 'a' again

b = raw_input()

#if b is a number then it should take next raw_input i.e., 'c' else it should ask for 'b' again

c = raw_input()

#if c is a number then it should take next raw_input i.e., 'd' else it should ask for 'c' again

## This should be done upto 'e'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `if..else` construct for the conditional checks and refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440952/how-do-i-check-if-raw-input-is-integer-in-python-2-7) for the integer check.

**Edit 1**

I have not executed it,but you could try the following and see if it works-

```
def ask(text):
    temp = raw_input(text)
    try:
        retVal = int(temp)
        return retVal
    except ValueError:
        return False

a = False
b = False
c = False

while not a:
    a = ask("Enter A:")
    if a == False:
        continue
    while not b:
        b = ask("ENter B:")
        if b == False:
            continue
        while not c:
            c = ask("Enter C:")
```

Comment: Hi, Mayur Buragohain.     Can you please code it from 'a' to 'e' raw_input. I am unable to do it!

Comment: Do accept the answer if it answered your query.

Answer (score 1):

use `a.isdigit()` to validate string `a` is digit or not

> str.isdigit()
>   Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

Comment: what about if it is a float value

Comment: @AnnasLee good catch. If your number contains dot(.) or slash(/) and so on, you can remove those characters and check. for example  `"1.1".replace(".", "").isdigit()`