# How to properly sort string with different number digits in Java?

Tags: java, android, zip

pardon my english.

with this code,

```
 Collections.sort(mEntries, new Comparator<ZipEntry>() {
            public int compare(ZipEntry a, ZipEntry b) {
                return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
            }
        });
```

when there are strings like this: `hello1,hello3,hello2,hello11,hello10`

it will be sorted into this: `hello1,hello10,hello11,hello2,hello3`

the result i want is this:

```
hello1,hello2,hello3,hello10,hello11
```

but when there are strings with the same number digits like this, it can properly sort it.

from this: `hello01,hello03,hello02,hello11,hello10.`

into this: `hello01,hello02,hello03,hello10,hello11`

any idea how can i achieve the result i want?

```
hello1,hello2,hello3,hello10,hello11
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The current sorting you are using is the natural (lexicographic) `String` sorting, derived by the invocation of `compareTo` on `String`s.

According to lexicographic sorting, `"10"` comes *before* `"2"`.

The sorting you want for `String`s with the same radix, ending with digits is a numerical sorting, which is the natural sorting for `Number`s (arithmetic).

According to the natural `Number` sorting, `10` will come *after* `2`.

What you want is to:

- Retrieve both `String`s
- Verify that their only difference is the last number (use regular expressions)
- If not, compare them lexicographically as you're already doing
- If instead, the only difference **is** the last number, then retrieve the last numbers and create two `Integer`s (through regex and the `Integer.parseInt` idiom)
- Then invoke the `compareTo` method on those `Integer`s and return the outcome

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, it works with this

```
  Collections.sort(mEntries, new Comparator<ZipEntry>() {
            public int compare(ZipEntry a, ZipEntry b) {


                return String.format("%100s", a.getName()).compareTo(
                        String.format("%100s", b.getName()));
            }
        });


        return null;
```

adopted from

[how to sort with different number of digits in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298319/how-to-sort-with-different-number-of-digits-in-java?rq=1)

Comment: this will still sort based on the string, but not based on the numbers as per your requirement. do you confirm this fixes your requirement?