# Python's Kivy FileBrowser doesn't index the files properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I've a Kivy app that has browse functionality. When browsing files with number names, it shows it in a weird way, it kind of sorts it by "most significant bit" style. Adding a screenshot.
Anyone knows how to fix it to show it in a proper order? (1,2,3... instead of 1,10,100...)

[image: Bad image indexing...]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a natural ordering. To do this, you need to replace the function that orders the files using the [`sort_func`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.sort_func) property of the class `kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController`.

An example based on the algorithm shown by @Darius Bacon in his answer to [Natural Sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34518/7131499):

**main.py**:

```
import re
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty




def natural_key(path):
    return [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in re.split(r'(\d+)', path)]


def natural_sort(files, filesystem):    
    return (sorted((f for f in files if filesystem.is_dir(f)), key = natural_key) +
            sorted((f for f in files if not filesystem.is_dir(f))))


class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    sort_func = ObjectProperty(natural_sort)



class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**main.kv:**

```
<RootWidget>:
    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'List View'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                FileChooserListView:
                    sort_func: root.sort_func


        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Icon View'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                FileChooserIconView:
                    sort_func: root.sort_func
```

Some screenshots as an example:

[image]

[image]